# WinJS Sample Code js file missing?

Tags: multi-device-hybrid-apps

"WinJS ToDo Sample for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps" Sample Code Project (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WinJS-TODO-Sample-for-17295485/sourcecode?fileId=114491&pathId=1137423199), I tried download and run it , but the index.html file include
three file for winjs reference : ./css/ui-light.css , ./scripts/frameworks/base.min.js , ./scripts/frameworks/ui.min.js , can't be found in the project .

what's i missing some thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample projects have been authored in a way that the requisite dependency frameworks will be automatically downloaded when you run the project for the first time.

However, the libraries may fail to download in case the script does not have the right permissions to execute. To fix this:

- Open the folder where you’ve downloaded the sample app
- Identify the FetchRequirements.ps1 file and right click it

[image]

- Choose “Properties”
- Click the Unblock button if it shows up

[image]

- Try to run the project again through Visual Studio

Comment: yes , i run this sample project , but that not downloaded any files about winjs library , and i got some error msg : 

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) File: ui-light.css, Line: 0, Column: 0
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) File: ui.min.js, Line: 0, Column: 0"

Comment: Did you follow the steps mentioned above to unblock the PowerShell file from your project folder?